# Integration with absolute value

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How do I integrate thing like this: $$\iint_M \left|\cos(x+y)\right|\,dx\,dy,\qquad M= [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$$ ? I can't understand on which areas I must divide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is not really a new answer, just an elaboration of the first one.]

If you divide the square defined by $0\le x\le \pi, 0\le y\le \pi$ into 3 pieces by drawing the lines

$\;\;\;x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x+y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$,

then $\cos(x+y)$ is positive in the two triangular regions and negative in the middle region.

This gives $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}\cos(x+y)dy\;dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}-x}^{\pi}\cos(x+y)dy\;dx$

$\hspace{.54 in}\displaystyle+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}^{\pi}-\cos(x+y)dy\;dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{3\pi}{2}-x}-\cos(x+y)dy\;dx$.

Answer (score 2):

With a change of variables $I$ becomes a one-dimensional integral:
$$ I = 2\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\pi-|\pi-s|)\,|\cos(s)|\,ds=4\int_{0}^{\pi}s\left|\cos(s)\right|\,ds, \tag{1}$$
then splitting $[0,\pi]$ into two equal pieces we get:
$$ I = 4\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}s\cos s\,ds+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-s\right)\cos s\,ds\right) = \color{red}{2\pi}.\tag{2}$$
Notice that this is just $\mu(M)$ times the average value of $|\cos x|$ over its period - not by chance, since the "tent function" $\pi-|\pi-s|$ is the Fourier transform of the Fejer kernel. Or, for the sake of simplicity, just notice that:
$$ I(y) = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\cos(x+y)\right|\,dx $$
does not really depend on $y$, since $|\cos x|$ is a $\pi$-periodic function, hence to compute $I(0)$ is enough for computing the double integral.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you substituted/changed the variables? I suspect you used $ \phi(x,y) = x + y $?

Comment: I used the usual $\frac{\pi}{4}$-rotation, $u=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}},v=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks. This question may seem dumb, but which transformation formula did you use?

Comment: The one I wrote :D Do you know how to change variables in double integrals?

Comment: I think I should know after measure theory and the bit of vector analysis I heard recently... just not familiar with it so far.

Comment: To rotate a domain by $45^\circ$ should not be so painful :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\iint_M |\cos(x+y)|dxdy
  = \iint_A \cos(x+y)dxdy - \iint_{M \backslash A} \cos(x+y)dxdy,
$$
where $A \subset [0,\pi]^2$ is a set over which $\cos(x+y) \geq 0$.

Recall that $\cos(x) \geq 0$ over $[0,2\pi]$ when $x \in [0,\pi/2] \cup [3\pi/2, 2\pi]$...

Comment: I think you meant $x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\cup \left[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right]$.

Comment: @rogerl thanks, fixed - confused sine and cosine

Comment: Yes, I understand that much, but then x here consists from x and y. I still don't know how to divide it.